# execute Webdav PROPFIND request using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, webdav

I want to perform Webdav PROPFIND request in javascript.
How can i do that?

Comment: Hello, I not familar in Webdav, so I looked up what you mean with "Webdav PROPFIND". I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142960%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx. It is this what that is?

Comment: Well, the same way as with any other HTTP method. It would be helpful if you explained what you have trouble with.

Comment: I am unable to perform the request. not receiving answer

Comment: a) show us the source code. b) try to obtain an HTTP trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

davclient.js is your answer.

http://debris.demon.nl/javascript/ (download davclient.js library)

API/docs included, but for your perusal right now:
http://debris.demon.nl/projects/davclient.js/doc/davclient.html

This JS library allows for a whole bunch of webdav functions via javascript, including propfinds.

If you figure out how to determine if a given resource is locked, or not, please reply.

Comment: isLocked() in the davfs API fyi, if you ever feel like revisiting this Q or accepting an answer, etc :P

Answer (score 0):

[it might be useful:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155260/webdav-with-curl-vs-javascript/61348763#61348763)

Furthermore, there is another library called [jsdavclient](https://github.com/svogler/jsdavclient/tree/6266030e82f6b2cfd97ebc2b172f99902541a667): I never tested it but maybe you can have a look at that

Comment: Please provide at least an example how to use this.